# Blow up the diagonal of a symmetric product space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

Consider the complex blow-up of the diagonal $\triangle\subset Sym^2(\mathbb{C}^n)$. It is known that the blown-up space is smooth when $n=1,2$. I was wondering if that is still smooth for $n\geq3$? Moreover, what if $\mathbb{C}^n$ is replaced by other complex variety? I'd be grateful if anyone could show me some hint or reference...

Comment: If true for $\Bbb{C}^n$, it will be true for any manifold -- this is a local question.

Comment: Another way to see it: a quotient of a smooth space by a free action is still smooth.

Comment: @DmitryVaintrob Do you mean blow up the product space first and then do the S_2-action? I don't see how that is free could you explain more? Thank you!

Comment: @EricYuan, good point! What I wrote above is incorrect (e.g. in the one-dimensional case the blow-up doesn't change the variety)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the quotient map $\pi:\mathrm{X}\times\mathrm{X}\rightarrow\mathrm{S}^2\mathrm{X}=(\mathrm{X}\times\mathrm{X})/\mathrm{S}_2$, and a point $p$ of $\mathrm{X}\times\mathrm{X}$. Then the tangent space of $\mathrm{S}^2\mathrm{X}$ at $\pi(p)$ equals the tangent space of $\mathrm{T}_p(\mathrm{X}\times\mathrm{X})/(\mathrm{S}_2)_p$ at the origin (see for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236546/how-to-compute-the-tangent-space-of-a-quotient-by-a-finite-group)), where $(\mathrm{S}_2)_p$ is the stabiliser of $p$. For $\mathrm{X}=\mathbf{A}^n$ you can also write down explicit equations for the blow up; another possibility is to prove that the blow up is isomorphic to the Hilbert scheme of two points $\mathrm{Hilb}^2\mathrm{X}$.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: @abx as the op is asking for a hint (not a complete explanation), I would say it does answer the question. But I guess I should have said that the answer to his question is yes.

Comment: Is it? I would be interested to see a proof.